# How to calculate the ⌉ operator?

Tags: finance

In a book about finance, the following formula appears:

$$\large a_{10 \,⌉\, 0.04}$$

What is this ⌉ operator and how to read / calculate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just a notation in Actuarial sciences

$a_{\overline{n|}i} := v + v^2 + \cdots + v^n = \frac{1-v^n}{i}$
,      where $v:=\frac{1}{i+1}$

Read this to know all notation of Actuarial sciences:
[Click Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actuarial_notation)

---

So,

$a_{\overline{10|}0.04}=\frac{1-(1+0.04)^{-10}}{0.04} \approx 8.111$

Comment: How would you apply this to my example?

Comment: Easy: n=10, i=0.04 => $a_{\overline{10|}0.04}=\frac{1-(1+0.04)^{-10}}{0.04}$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. :)